# Join Two MySQL Table and Display Result in Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table called t_user and t_chat. I am trying to display message from t_chat in PHP table like below.

```
     $quotes_qry="SELECT * FROM t_chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
     $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,$quotes_qry);
    <?php   
                            $i=0;
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {   

                        ?>
                            <tr>

                              <td><?php echo ++$sr+$start;?></td> 
                              <td><?php echo $row['sender'];?></td>                
                              <td><?php echo nl2br($row['receiver']);?></td>
                              <td><?php echo nl2br($row['message']);?></td>
                              <td><?php echo time_elapsed_string($row['time']);?></td>
                              <td><a href="?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?');"><img src="images/delete-icon.png"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                    <?php
$i++;
                        }
                ?>
```

I want display sender and receiver name which is located in table called `t_user with username column`. I am new in PHP and confused how can I achieve it. Let me know if someone can help me for achieve my task. Thanks a lot!

Note : t_chat table have userid witch column name called sender and receiver, currently I am displaying that userid in above table, instead I want display username.
Thanks

Comment: Is there also a username column in the t_chat table?

Comment: @tshimkus We have user_id of sender and receiver in t_chat table, not username. I want get username from t_user. Thanks

Comment: You could use an SQL JOIN - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: To join tables you need a field that is present in both tables that you can use to match records. Do you have anything that would work like that? Are they unique (only one row with that index)?

Comment: @tshimkus yes in table t_user id is same as t_chat have sender and receiver. Both are common in both table. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joins might look something like this:

```
SELECT t_chat.sender AS 'sender', t_chat.receiver AS 'receiver', t_chat.message AS 'message', t_chat.time AS 'time', t_chat.id AS 'id', user1.username AS 'senderusername', user2.username AS 'receiverusername'  
FROM t_chat 
LEFT JOIN t_user AS user1 ON t_chat.sender = user1.id
LEFT JOIN t_user AS user2 ON t_chat.receiver = user2.id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

In this example I am joining the tables twice (as user1 and user2) so that the `t_user` table gets referenced independently for each lookup.

I also gave each column a name using `AS` to make them easier to reference later in your code.

Comment: error in first line called "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'sender' (T_STRING) in"

Comment: My bad. You have the query wrapped in double quotes so the string is getting broken up. Replace all the double quotes in my example with single quotes or escape them like this `\"`

Comment: Yeah, I have solved it and sorry, but I don't know how I can display value from it?

Comment: Same way you were doing it before: `$row['message']`, `$row['senderusername']`, etc.  The `AS` gives the columns unique names so you don't have to type `$row['t_chat.message']` to access that column.

Comment: query does not giving any error but its also not displaying anything in table. Thanks

Comment: Maybe replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`? That should ensure that all the records from `t_chat` are being returned. Do those conditions look correct on the join statements? Will `t_chat.sender` match with `t_user.username`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187790/discussion-between-raju-bhatt-and-tshimkus).

Comment: updated for accuracy. `id` from `t_user` matched to `sender` and `receiver` columns in `t_chat`

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql (The t_user table must have an `id` column that matches the `userid` from t_chat):

```
$quotes_qry="SELECT t1.sender, t1.receiver, t1.message, t1.time, t2.username FROM t_chat AS t1 INNER JOIN t_user AS t2 ON t1.userid=t2.id ORDER BY t1.id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

More details and examples about MySQL JOIN you can find in the tutorial from:

https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/mysql-inner-left-join-right-join_t